# Unable to use array as a method parameter

Tags: php

I have two classes. In my parent class I have this function:

```
protected function assign($items, $array)
    {
        foreach($items as $item)
        {
            $array[$item] = $item;
        }

        return $array;
    }
```

I use the second array parameter to determine which array to append to.
Then I call it from my child class like this.

```
$this -> assign($this -> attributes, $this -> values);
```

That doesn't work but if I hardcode the name of the array in the parent class to `$this -> values` then it works as it should. I want to know what I am doing wrong and how to do it correctly.

Thanks

Comment: You function parameter is trans by value, and you didn't use the return value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code

```
protected function assign($items, &$array)
    {
        foreach($items as $item)
        {
            $array[$item] = $item;
        }

        return $array;
    }
```

Comment: added an & before $array